# Изменение границ ячеек в заголовке

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Есть таблица из нескольких столбцов. Между первым и вторым и вторым и третьим столбцами не должно быть границ. В самом теле таблицы проблему решил использованием разных стилей для ячеек столбцов. Для заголовка таблицы написан свой стиль

```
<!--All border-->
<Style x:Key="ShowAllBorder" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -1 -1 0" />
</Style>

<!--Hide Right Border Column-->
<Style x:Key="HideRightCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -1 -1 0" />
</Style>

<!--Hide Left Border Column-->
<Style x:Key="HideLeftCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 1 1 1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -1 -1 0" />
</Style>

<!--Hide LeftRight Border Column-->
<Style x:Key="HideLeftRightCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 1 0 1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -1 -1 0" />
</Style>

<!--Header Column-->
<Style x:Key="DGridCentAl" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Thumb.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1, 0, -1, 10" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 0 1 0" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3F3F3F" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
</Style>
```

Таблица получается следующая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно убрать границы между первым и вторым и вторым и третьим столбцом в заголовке?

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему, создав отдельные стили для заголовков каждого столбца

```
<!--Header Column-->
<Style x:Key="DGridCentAl" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Thumb.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 10" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3F3F3F" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="HideLeftRight" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Thumb.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BFBFBF" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 10" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3F3F3F" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
</Style>
```

и применив их для первых трёх столбцов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]